# How to know if user has entered invalid $routeparams

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I can access query url params using

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function () {    
    var id = $routeParams.id
   //check if user has entered any params other than "id".
   //if yes do someting
});
```

I need to prevent user from entering params other than "id".

eg:

`example.com/?id="something"` is accepted

`example.com/?junk="something"` should be rejected.

Is there any way for this?

Comment: Maybe i don't understand your question :)
But why not if(id ='checkyourId'){ // do something }else { // show an alert or popup}

Comment: I would just clean out the `routeParams`. Remove anything that isn't what you'd expect!

Comment: you can manually parse the `$routeParams` object.

Comment: I agree with Callum Linington, this is certainly the best way. If  users put a wrong params delete params.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating what the guys are saying the comments you could do something like the following where you are initialising your app (in the run function or in a root controller) or within your routeUpdate listener:

```
if($location.search.id){
    $location.search({id:$location.search.id}));
} else {
    $location.search({});
}
```

Obviously you'll need to inject the $location into the DI (add it as a param in that function scope - the scope your listener is in in your question).